# how to create a delete button when onclick checkbox in jsp?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to display or insert a button on jsp page when onclick checkbox.this is my code.
it doesnt work.this is my index.jsp page
can anyone help me ??

JSP Page

```
     function validateForm()
    {   var validfirstUsername = document.form.text1.value.match(/^[A-Za-z ]{3,20}$/);
        var validage=document.form.text2.value.match(/^[1-9]?[0-9]{1}$|100/);
        var validphoneno = document.form.text3.value.match(/^\d{10}$/);  


      if(validfirstUsername == null){
      alert("Your first name is not valid");
      document.form.text1.value = "";
      return false;
      }
      if(validage ==null){
      alert("Your  age is not valid");
      document.form.text2.value = "";
      return false;
      }
       if( validphoneno==null){
      alert("Your phone no is not valid");
      document.form.text3.value = "";
      return false;
      }
}                       


   </script>
</head>
<body style= "background-image: url(index.jpeg);background-repeat:no-repeat;" >
    <div id="new"> 
 <%! 
  Connection con;
  PreparedStatement ps;
  ResultSet rs;
  String q;

   %>

 <% try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jspdatabase","root", "kca@fnpl#12");
  Statement st=con.createStatement();
 }catch(Exception e){}%>


  <h1>Enter student details....</h1>
  <%! public void checkid(String a){%>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete" />


     <%!  }%>



  <form name="form" action="submit.jsp"method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"> 
      <center> Name:&nbsp<input type="text" name="text1" value="" /><br><br>
        Age :&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="text2" value="" /><BR><br>
        Sex :&nbsp &nbsp  male<input type="radio" name="bg" value="male"/>
        female<input type="radio" name="bg" value="female" /><BR><br>
        phone no:<input type="text" name="text3" value="" /><BR><br>
        Date:<select name="date">
            <% for(int i=1;i<32;i++){%>
            <option><%=i%></option>
            <%}%>

        </select>
        <select name="month">
             <% for(int i=1;i<13;i++){%>
            <option><%=i%></option>
            <%}%>

        </select>
        <select name="year">
             <% for(int i=1990;i<1996;i++){%>
            <option><%=i%></option>
            <%}%>

        </select><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />


  </form>   



        <% 
         q="select id,name,age,sex,phone,date,mark1,mark2 from table1";
         try{
         ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
         rs = ps.executeQuery();
         }
         catch(Exception e){

        }%>
          <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>selection</th>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>age</th>
                    <th>sex</th>
                    <th>phone</th>
                    <th>date_of_birth</th>
                    <th>mark1</th>
                    <th>mark2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        <% 
                while(rs.next())
        {
         %>                
         <tr>
             <td><input type="checkbox"  name="check"  value="off" onClick="checkid(<%=rs.getString(1) %>);"/></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
                     <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                      <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
                       <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
                        <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td> 
                          <td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td>
                           <td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
                            <td><%=rs.getString(8)%></td>


                </tr>  

       <%}


          %>

</tbody>
            </table>

           </center>

        </form>
    </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

thanx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `checkid` function is under `<%` tag and run on server side meanwhile the `onclick=` will executes javascript only, that is client side.

Create a client-side function `checkid`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function checkid(id) {
    $('#delete_button').show();
}
</script>
<input type="button" id="delete_button" style="display: none" value="Delete"/>
```

Comment: Just put that code into somewhere in your jsp, outside of the `<%` tag, that is.

Answer (score 0):

when checkbox clicked

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() 
   {
     alert($(this).is(":checked"));
     //Or you could use alert($(this).attr("checked") == "checked");
   });
});
```

based on checked write function

Comment: @Sridhar..i want this in jsp

Comment: ya it will work in jsp.add jquery in head and call that function